# Exporting data from multiple SQL tables to different flat files using SSIS Script Task

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datagridview, ssis

I am trying to create a datagrid and export the contents to a text file using VB.NET and I am doing this inside an SSIS script task in order to automate the process to export a dynamic table to text file. I don't get any error and the files are created but the files are empty.

What am I doing wrong here in this code?

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim FName As String = "D:\test.TXT"

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If File.Exists(FName) Then
        File.Delete(FName)
    End If
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=localhost;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2008R2;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Table")
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "Test")

    Dim DataGrid1 As New DataGrid
    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager
    Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    Dim dgvc As DataGridViewCell
    Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FName)

    For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        Dim intCellCount As Integer = dgvr.Cells.Count
        Dim intCounter As Integer = 1

        For Each dgvc In dgvr.Cells()
            If intCounter <> intCellCount Then
                sw.Write(dgvc.Value.ToString & "|")
            Else
                sw.WriteLine(dgvc.Value.ToString)
            End If

            intCounter += 1
        Next
    Next

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible way of exporting the tables of different structure to flat file using `Script Task`. This example will export two tables containing different fields and data to a flat file using Script Task. In order to export the data, you can use the `DataReader` instead of using the `DataGrid`. There could be other possible ways to do this.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create three tables named `dbo.TablesList`,  `dbo.Source1` and  `dbo.Source2` using the scripts given under **SQL Scripts** section.
2. Populate the tables `dbo.TablesList`,  `dbo.Source1` and  `dbo.Source2`` with data shown in screenshot #**1**.
3. On the SSIS package's `Connection manager`, create an `OLE DB connection` named **SQLServer** to connect to the SQL Server instance as shown in screenshot #**2**.
4. In the package, create 4 variables as shown in screenshot #**3**.
5. In the Control Flow, place an `Execute SQL Task`, a `Foreach Loop Container` and a `Script Task` within the `Foreach loop container` as shown in screenshot #**4**.
6. Configure the `Execute SQL task` as shown in screenshots #**5** and #**6**.
7. Configure the `Foreach Loop container` as shown in screenshots #**7** and #**8**.
8. Replace the Main method inside the Script Task with the code given under the section `Script Task Code`.
9. Screenshot #**9** shows package execution.
10. Screenshots #**10** - #**12** show the files exported from SSIS using Script Task code.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Source1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source2](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [StateProvince] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Source2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TablesList](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FilePath] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tables] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Script Task Code:** (Use the code given below to replace the Main() method in your Script task)

**VB** Main() method code that can be used in **`SSIS 2005 and above`**:

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim varCollection As Variables = Nothing

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::TableName")
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::FileName")
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::Delimiter")
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(varCollection)

    Dim fileName As String = varCollection("User::FileName").Value.ToString()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & varCollection("User::TableName").Value.ToString()
    Dim delimiter As String = varCollection("User::Delimiter").Value.ToString()

    Dim writer As StreamWriter = Nothing
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(Dts.Connections("SQLServer").ConnectionString)
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing

    Try
        If File.Exists(fileName) Then
            File.Delete(fileName)
        End If

        connection.Open()
        command = New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then

            writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName)
            Dim row As Integer = 0
            While reader.Read()

                Dim header As Integer = 0
                Dim counter As Integer = 0
                Dim fieldCount As Integer = reader.FieldCount - 1

                If row = 0 Then
                    While header <= fieldCount
                        If header <> fieldCount Then
                            writer.Write(reader.GetName(header).ToString() & delimiter)
                        Else
                            writer.WriteLine(reader.GetName(header).ToString())
                        End If
                        header += 1
                    End While
                End If

                While counter <= fieldCount
                    If counter <> fieldCount Then
                        writer.Write(reader(counter).ToString() & delimiter)
                    Else
                        writer.WriteLine(reader(counter).ToString())
                    End If
                    counter += 1
                End While

                row += 1
            End While
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        writer.Close()
    End Try

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

Comment: Hi, and thank you for stepping in, I'm actually pulling a list of tables into a foreachloop, so can't use flat file destination as columns are different and can't use OLE as input columns are different, SSIS doesn't do that on the fly! – that's why i'm using the above code, and for simplicity i've removed the variable and added a table in the query so people can further understand my requirment, nut looks like I wasn't clear enough.  but thanks again

Comment: Great, yes works fine, the code is all what I was looking for, thanks so much....god bless for sharing the knowledge

Comment: Thanks siva, By the way I was playing earlier with the DataReader, but couldn't do the counter part, also with the GRID I was hoping to get the column names, that's why I was trying it.

Comment: @Siva: I couldn't find the screenshots in your answer. Please provide the same soon.

Comment: @Siva: Still I couldn't able to see any screenshot even i tried in IE 9.0, Firefox 11.0, Google Chrome browsers.

Comment: Just as a note on this. The  writer.Close() is technically in the wrong place and should be at the end of the while. If there are no rows in the table your exporting then the writer won't be instantiated throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an OLEDB source component, put your table query in there and then output it to a flat file writer in SSIS instead of using a script component? [This blog post](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/ssis-exporting-data-to-a-text-file-using-a-package/) illustrates how to do this.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for stepping in, I'm actually pulling a list of tables into a foreachloop, so can't use flat file destination as columns are different and can't use OLE as input columns are different, SSIS doesn't do that on the fly!